# Does the order of jQueryUI Dialogs make a difference (maybe just with TinyMCE)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce, jquery-ui-dialog

In the script below (live example is located at http://jsbin.com/aliket/1/ with source code located at http://jsbin.com/aliket/1/edit), I created two dialogs, where one (#dialog2) is a child within the other (#dialog1).  If I create #dialog2 before #dialog1, open #dialog1 and then open #dialog2, the TinyMCE plugin no longer works.  By not working, I mean TinyMCE's text box is shaded out and any previously entered HTML is gone.  Is this a problem with the order of the two dialogs, or TinyMCE?  Why is it happening?  I do know how to fix it,however: just create #dialog1 before #dialog2.  Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="click1">Click 1</button>
        <div id="dialog1" title="dialog1"><div id="tinymce"></div><button id="click2">Click 2</button></div>
        <div id="dialog2" title="dialog2">Hello</div>
    </body>

    <script>
        tinymce.init({selector: "#tinymce"});
        $(function() {
            $('#click2').click(function(){$("#dialog2").dialog("open");});
            $("#dialog2").dialog({autoOpen:false,resizable:false,height:300,width:240,modal:true});
            $("#click1").click(function(){$("#dialog1").dialog("open");});
            $("#dialog1").dialog({autoOpen: false,modal: true});    
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is your jsbin with jquery loaded: http://jsbin.com/azokic/1/edit

Comment: @roasted.  Yes, I believe it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you did not shut down your editor instance before you opened another one with the same id. Use the mceCommand `mceRemoveControl` to shut such an editor instance down.

Comment: I am not sure.  Note that if `#click1` is created first, the condition doesn't exist.  See http://jsbin.com/aliket/3/ for an example.

Comment: Also, off topic, but I think there is a better way of shutting down an instance than `mceRemoveControl`.  See http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=31062 for how I am attempting to do so with TinyMCE 4, but use `editor.remove()` instead of `editor.hide()`.

Comment: Ok, i had a closer look at your example. Your problem has nothing to do with shuting down an editor. I have not been able to find the problem, but i suggest you file a bug report to moxiecode: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_bugs.php . Tinymce4 is still beta and this needs to get fixed.

Comment: Thanks Thariama.  Will do.